# GAE behavior when relocating an application to another server

Tags: google-app-engine

Two questions:

1. Does Google App Engine send any kind of message to an application just before relocating it to another server?
2. If so, what is that message?

Answer (score 3):

No it doesnt. It doesnt relocate either, old instances keep running (and eventually stop when idle for long enough) while new ones are spawned.

Answer (score 1):

There are times when App Engine needs to move your instance to a different machine to improve load distribution.

> When App Engine needs to turn down a manual scaling instance it first
> notifies the instance. There are two ways to receive this
> notification. First, the is_shutting_down() method from
> google.appengine.api.runtime begins returning true. Second, if you
> have registered a shutdown hook, it will be called. It's a good idea
> to register a shutdown hook in your start request. After the
> notification is issued, existing requests are given 30 seconds to
> complete, and new requests immediately return 404.
>
> If an instance is
> handling a request, App Engine pauses the request and runs the
> shutdown hook. If there is no active request, App Engine sends an
> /_ah/stop request, which runs the shutdown hook. The /_ah/stop request
> bypasses normal handling logic and cannot be handled by user code; its
> sole purpose is to invoke the shutdown hook. If you raise an exception
> in your shutdown hook while handling another request, it will bubble
> up into the request, where you can catch it.

The following code sample demonstrates a basic shutdown hook:

```
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
from google.appengine.api import runtime

def my_shutdown_hook():
  apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.CancelApiCalls()
  save_state()
  # May want to raise an exception

runtime.set_shutdown_hook(my_shutdown_hook)
Alternatively, the following sample demonstrates how to use the is_shutting_down() method:
while more_work_to_do and not runtime.is_shutting_down():
  do_some_work()
  save_state()
```

More details here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_states